# Linux Mint 12: Can't Create gnome-terminal Profiles

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am trying to setup some gnome-terminal profiles, so that I can have a pre-configured set of tabs when I start gnome-terminal.  Previously I achieved this by going to Edit=>Profiles... (in gnome-terminal), adding a new profile, and then using `gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=ThatProfile`.

However, this is not working on my new (Linux Mint 12) box.  I can create profiles just fine, but when I try to run them with --tab-with-profile, I get an error "No such profile "test", using default profile".  If I then check `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles`, sure enough the only profile listed is Default.

So, it seems like gnome-terminal is creating profiles *somewhere*, because the profiles I create show up in gnome-terminal itself.  However, they're not getting created in `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles`, and they're not getting created in wherever gnome-terminal actually looks for profiles (when you use --tab-with-profile).

Does anyone have any idea what's going?

.................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a clear idea what is going on, but I suppose that some mismatch is happening between some parts of the gnome-terminal software. This might be solved in later releases.

You could try to search for the profiles by name over the entire disk.
If found, you could copy them manually to the profiles folder.

I also wonder whether "Terminal > Change Profile" does work with your profiles.
If this works, then the bug is in the tab-with-profile parameter.

If the question doesn't get solved here,
perhaps you could also ask it on the
[Linux Mint Forums](http://forums.linuxmint.com/).

Comment: Change Profile lists my profiles, but does nothing when I try to switch to them (I set an "Initial title" in a profile, but when I open a new tab with that profile it still says "Terminal").  Sounds like maybe there's a bug in the latest Mint; I'll try their forums, thanks.